# Manejar bloqueos en un entorno concurrente

Tags: sql, sql-server, tsql, sql-server-2014

Estoy trabajando en un sistema con 15 procesos concurrentes que realizan varias operaciones contra una base de datos SQL SERVER, las versiones pueden ir desde 2005 a 2014.
Cada proceso tiene sus datos particulares en varias tablas, ningún proceso consulta / elimina / updatea / inserta información de otros procesos. Tenemos tres tablas involucradas, R, E y P, el proceso principal se ejecuta en un procedimiento almacenado con un transacción. Las operaciones que hace son en esta secuencia:

BEGIN TRANSACION UNCOMMITED

1. INSERTA CIENTOS DE FILAS EN R
2. UPDATE en P con FK del id del proceso estableciendo la máxima fecha de R
3. DELETE E con FK del id del proceso y filtrando por fechas
4. INSERT INTO E SELECT FROM R FK del id del proceso y filtrando por fechas

COMMIT

Cada cierto tiempo aparecen interbloqueos, lo que he hecho es crear un índice CLUSTERED para processID y para el campo fecha en la tabla R y en la tabla E.
También he creado índices NON CLUSTERED para ambas tablas incluyendo estos campos processID, date y algunos más.

He establecido READUNCOMMITED porque no tengo problemas con las dirty read al no compartir información entre procesos, he deshabilitado el LOCK SCALATION. El rendimiento parece aceptable pero quería intentar mejorarlo. Cuando se provoca el deadlock lo que hago es reintentar la transacción y en la mayoría de casos se ejecuta convenientemente. Tengo entendido que el consumo de memoria podría incrementarse al establecer LOCK SCALATION  a DISABLE. También podría desactivar los ROW_lock y page_lock en los índices, pero no se si esto sería adecuado. ¿Cómo podría mejorar este entorno para permitir la concurrencia existente? ¿Qué otros mecanismos podría integrar? Gracias

Comment: Con la información que nos das es complicado entender el problema, pero te puedo decir lo siguiente: el transaction isolation READ UNCOMMITED permite dirty read. Es el nivel de aislamiento que permite mayor concurrencia, pero no evita los deadlocks. Para evitar los deadlocks deberías usar como mínimo SNAPSHOT o preferiblemente SERIALIZABLE. ¿Puedes agregar información del schema?

Comment: Te comento, quizá te ayude algo, lo que hice en una situación similar se alta concurrencia. En mi casi se generaban ``dead lock`` entre procesos. Lo solucioné creando una tabla a la que llame semáforo que contenía  una sola columna donde cada fila   contenía un identificador del proceso que le correspondía. Y como te imqginaras cualquier proceso tenía que hacer un read for update antes de entrar a la zona critica y al salir de esta liberaban el recurso y entraba el siguiente que estaba esperando por el recurso. Esto evitó los dead-lock porque los procesos se encolaban en funcion al recurso.

Answer (score 1):

Los problemas de bloqueos se producen cuando varios procesos compiten por actualizar los mismos registros. Esto no es un problema si los procesos son suficientemente rápidos, porque todos los trabajos se van encolando y procesando conforme entran. No acabo de entender del todo lo que realiza tu proceso, pero normalmente esto lo suelo resolver de dos formas:

- Separando tablas para cada proceso: Si puedes, lo ideal es que cada proceso utilice sus tablas y en el último paso (el insert), lo hagas sobre la tabla definitiva común a todos.
- Replanteando el proceso: Verifica que todas las acciones que realiza son necesarias y que están justificadas. Piensa si se podría hacer de otra manera, identifica que procesos son los que CONSUMEN MÁS TIEMPO de ejecución y trata de darles otro planteamiento.

Como normal general también puedes revisar los índices que tienes en las tablas. Los índices mejoran el rendimiento en las consultas pero penalizan el resto de operaciones de inserción y actualización. Verifica que tienes los índices estrictamente necesarios. Elimina todos los que no necesites y si puedes intenta hacer operaciones en bloques más pequeños de registros. Te dejo un pequeño script para que veas como realizar una tarea básica de ejemplo:

```
DECLARE @RowCount INT
SET @RowCount = 1
WHILE (@RowCount > 0) 
BEGIN  
    delete from [XXXXX] where Pky IN (
        select top 500 [XXXXXX].Pky
        from [XXXXXX] with (nolock)
        inner join [YYYYYYYY] with (nolock) ON [XXXXXX].AAAAA = [YYYYYYY].BBBBB
    )
    SET @RowCount = @@ROWCOUNT
    WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:05'
END
```

En cualquier caso, te remito a mis dos comentarios del principio. Primero verifica que el proceso lo tienes planteado correctamente y que no hay una manera de hacerlo mejor, si no la hay, verifica el tema de los índices y finalmente, intenta hacerlo usando procesos más cortos utilizando scripts como el que te pongo de ejemplo.